# Arabic excel file to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, arabic

I have an Excel file with data in Arabic. How can I import this in an sqlite database for use in an Android application? I tried to export as CSV, but Excel doesn't export the csv as unicode, so the data is unreadable.

Comment: In what encoding does Excel export?

Comment: I believe it's UTF-8. I'm on OSX and I can't set in the excel the encoding when I save the file.

Comment: SQLite *always* uses UTF-8. Please show an example text and how it ends up.

Comment: Possible duplicate to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458074/import-csv-file-contain-arabic-data-to-sqllite?). It might have a possible answer.