# import csv file contain arabic data to sqllite

Tags: android, excel, sqlite, csv, arabic

I have an excel file with data in arabic. How can I import this in an sqlite database for use in an Android application? I tried to export as CVS, but excel doesn’t export the cvs as unicode, so the data is unreadable

Comment: use LibreOffice to export it.

Comment: more explanation please

Comment: you state `excel doesn’t export the cvs as unicode`. I recommend you change your tool, and I think LibreOffice does support unicode CSV export.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question has been asked for a while now but I actually encountered the same issue and solved it by following the below steps:

1. Open your excel sheet (.xls or .xlsx)
2. Save it in Unicode Text (.txt) format
3. Open the text file and change the encoding to UTF-8
4. Replace the delimiter (which could be Tab delimited) by a comma
5. Make sure the file is readable and as you expect it to be (you might need a minor manual modification in some cases)
6. Rename the file back to (.csv)